# Bootstrap Modal Controlling While Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I was doing my project & I need Some Help in my project. The Following Represents The HTML Code for That:

```
<a href="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> LogIn/Sign-Up</a>
```

The Above Code Will Represent The Following Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="f1" action="index.php" id="loginform" onsubmit="return validatelogin();" method="post" role="form">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="errorDiv1">
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsername3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtuname" id="inputlUsername3" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                            <input type="password" name="txtpwd2" class="form-control" id="inputlPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#registermodal" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">Register Here</a>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

That Will Redirect to The  Function as follows:

```
function validatelogin(){
    $unme2=document.getElementById("inputlUsername3").value;
    $lpwd2=document.getElementById("inputlPassword3").value;
    if($unme2=="" || $lpwd2=="")
    {
        $("#errorDiv1").addClass('alert alert-danger');
        $("#errorDiv1").html("Please fill all fields.");
        return false;   
    }
    else
    {
        //php code for authentication
    }
}
```

Now I want Suggestion That How I can have the error at the same modal while the username is wrong or password is incorrect without redirecting to anyother page.

The following represents the php code:

```
<?php
    $uname=$_POST['txtuname'];
    $pwd2=$_POST['txtpwd2'];
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("onlineshop",$con);
    $r=mysql_query("select password from users where username='$uname'",$con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($r);
    $val=$row[0];

    if($val!="")
    {
        if($pwd2==$val)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username']=$uname;
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        else 
        {
            $msg="Invalid UN/PW";   
        }
    }
?>
```

Please Do Reply Soon

Comment: You will need to apply some asynchronous method or redirect to the same page passing the error to it and triggering the modal to open onload.

Comment: @Bhargav You can use jquery validation for modal form.

Comment: @frz3993 can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: @vipulpatel please do show me how to do that?

Comment: I dont Know How to trigger a model to open on load

Comment: On Ajax success you can use $("#myModel").modal('show')

Answer (score 0):

Use your code in following manner 
for more info about `ajax` [click here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
function validatelogin(){
            $unme2=document.getElementById("inputlUsername3").value;
            $lpwd2=document.getElementById("inputlPassword3").value;
            if($unme2=="" || $lpwd2=="")
            {
                $("#errorDiv1").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                $("#errorDiv1").html("Please fill all fields.");
                return false;   

            }
            else
                {
                    //php code for authentication
                  sendDataToServer();
                }
        }

function sendDataToServer(){
  
  var username= document.getElementById("inputlUsername3").value;
  var password= document.getElementById("inputlPassword3").value;
  
   $.ajax({
    url:'index.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{
       username:username,
       password:password,
    },
    success:function(data){
   
      if(data['flag']=='correct'){
            alert('username and password correct');
            // move to home page or some other page
        }else{
          // if you are here means username and password are incorrect
          // show an alert or can show a hide div
          }
      },
      error:function(){
  
      }
  });
   
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> LogIn/Sign-Up</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>Login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="errorDiv1">
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputUsername3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtuname" id="inputlUsername3" placeholder="Username">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                    <input type="password" name="txtpwd2" class="form-control" id="inputlPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#registermodal" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">Register Here</a>
                        <input type="button" name="submit" id="checkButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: how about the php code of the database, should there be need any change? The modal will not be closed until the username and p/w are correct, else show the error in the modal with alert-danger class.

Comment: php code will be same you just need to send revert from the php page through which u can know that entered username/password correct or not

Comment: Where do I write the php code and I request you to show how to revert?

Comment: I don't have any idea about php but for revert response you use `setContentType("application/json");` and write data as `write("{\"flag\":\"correct\"}")`